# Using object name with in the <> , as new ArrayList<String> is correct or it is ok to used only <>?

Tags: java, sonarqube, generic-programming

I created generics like  below (1) way , but when Sonar gives me error to replace ,it has (2) . I need to know , what is the best and correct way create generics using <> operator .

- 1

Noncompliant Code Example

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();  // Noncompliant
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();  // Noncompliant
```

- 2

Compliant Solution

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Sonar Code Analysis given below warning :

ava 7 introduced the diamond operator (<>) to reduce the verbosity of generics code. For instance, instead of having to declare a List's type in both its declaration and its constructor, you can now simplify the constructor declaration with <>, and the compiler will infer the type.

Note that this rule is automatically disabled when the project's sonar.java.source is lower than 7.

Comment: What are you asking? You already wrote the solution using `<>`.

Comment: you don't create Generics using <>. The point is that in previous versions of Java, you had to specify which type it was, on both ends of the assignment symbol ( = ), while in newer Java versions, only the declaration part needs to have the explicit type

Comment: @Eran what is most best solution with<T> or without using T <> ?

Comment: If you are asking what is the best way then second option using <> is.  as you need not to write extra code which is useless.

Comment: @uma List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(); is preferrable over List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); . Not only do you provide a Type to set the Type (which was already set earlier), meaning pointless code, it's just an added place where you can make a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, using the diamond operator (introduced in Java 7) as:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

is better due to letting the compiler to infer the arguments as per the declared type.

See also: [Java 7: Do we really need <> in the diamond operator?](https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-do-we-really-need)